# How do I validate form input against a max value pulled from a model?

Tags: angularjs

I have this form:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.cartItems">
    <div class="col-sm-4 cartItemLabel" ng-bind-html="item.label">  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
         <input class="form-control input" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty" max="item.maxqty">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1 inputItemValue">
       <span ng-bind="item.maxqty"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 inputItemValue">
       <span ng-bind="item.value | currency:USD$:2"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1 inputItemValue">
       $
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-model="item.subTotal">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 error" ng-show="form.item.id.$invalid">
     <small class="error" ng-show="form.item.id.$error.max">
        You exceeded the maximum allowed
     </small>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The value for max is set to item.maxqty, which is pulled from JSON in my model. All values are populated correctly. I just can't seem to get the validation to work. Any ideas? The important bit of the code is deep in the bushes :) So, here is the line I need to validate:

```
<input class="form-control input" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty" max="item.maxqty">
```

Comment: as i see your input does not have any validation

Comment: What I read said to add the max= bit to the input. I put that on the input with item.qty, which is what I want to validate against the max (item.maxqty). How should I do this differently?

Answer (score 2):

You have a max in an input type="text". It ll not work if it´s not a number one. Is that?

Must be

```
<input class="form-control input" type="number" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty" max="item.maxqty">
```

**EDIT**
Also, the item $valid is ok for that

```
<div class="col-sm-2" ng-hide="form.item.id.$valid" >
<small class="error" ng-show="form.item.id.$error.max">You exceeded the maximum </small>
</div>
```

anyway, you´ll not see that validation until the model is bigger, i supose (the input will not allow you to enter a number bigger than the max) [check this fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/AygmEuizJSHAx4W9GD4D) in plnkr

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-number-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="numberExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('numberExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.example = {
        value: 12
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Number
    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="0" max="10" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.max">
      THIS IS A BIG NUMBER!</span>
  </div>
  <h1> PLEASE TRY TO PUT A NUMBER BIGGER THAN 10</h1>
  <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.max = {{myForm.input.$max}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can enter a number above the max manually (on the keyboard). The initial number is above the max anyways

Comment: Thanks so much. However, my implementation still does not work. I think the dynamic call to the input name attribute is causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: a dynamic call for an input?? I don´t understand. You mean de ng-model retrieved??

Comment: Yes. I have since found that you cannot bind the input name to a model. I have to find a workaround.

Comment: When watching your code yesterday, i feel confuse with item.id  use.

I think it may cause problemes with form.item.id <-- it should look for   a `form{ item :{id:0}}`  insn´t it??

Comment: try to avoid that. maybe is better to create a new specific variable. (not completely sure on your code!! don´t follow me, just remember it)

Comment: you´re welcome!! I´ve just started to answer on stackoverflow and i love it!! :) Sincerelly, thanks!!

Comment: Guys how is that answer acceptable. The error isn't getting triggered. The input when typing isn't being applied a max value. This is not for this particulr answer only. For the majority of stack overflow answers to this question, it si the same thing.